# iGCSE Further Maths Vectors Question

Tags: geometry, vectors

This is a question from an iGCSE further maths paper, which I am currently working on, but I simply do not even know how to go about answering **part (b)** of the following question with no extra information (e.g. Angles/unit vectors) given - I have completed part (a), the very easy part. I have been trying to complete this question for hours, going about it with many different methods with no results, and I am simply stumped, hence why I have come here looking for an answer/method with so little information (sorry). I would appreciate any help. Preemptively, thank you.

[image: Further Maths Question]

Comment: $NM$ is parallel to $AB$ and area of $ABNM$ is twice the area of $ONM$. Area of $ONM$ is $\frac{1}{2}|\vec{ON} \times \vec{OM}|$ where $\times$ indicates the vector cross product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We know that

$$\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}=11\vec p-(5\vec p-3\vec q)=6\vec p+3\vec q=3(2\vec p+\vec q)$$

$$\vec{AC}=\vec{OC}-\vec{OA}=13\vec p+\vec q-(5\vec p-3\vec q)=8\vec p+4\vec q=4(2\vec p+\vec q)$$

and then $\vec{AC}=\frac{4}{3}\vec{AB}$.

That give us:

$$\frac{\text{area}(OAC)}{\text{area}(OAB)}=\frac{4}{3}\quad (1)$$

once $M$ and $N$ are midpoints then

$$\frac{\text{area}(OMN)}{\text{area}(OAB)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\to \frac{\text{area}(ABNM)}{\text{area}(OAB)}=\frac{3}{4} \quad(2)$$

now calculate $(2)/(1)$ and get:

$$\frac{\text{area}(ABNM)}{\text{area}(OAC)}=\frac{9}{16}$$

Comment: Thank you so much - an extremely helpful, comprehensive and easy-to-understand answer! I fully understand how to do this now!

Comment: @SaulMcShane: you are very welcome!